# How to create objects from multiple selectors in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two elements`(#list1, #list2 in html)`. I need to create object and populate it from these two elements. 
For example:

```
$('#list1, #list2').each(function(index,value){ 
  var object =[ {#list1.value, #list2.value} ]; 
})
```

Something like that. So it can add these elements to array with each iteration. How it can be done?

Comment: Please show sample html and expected results

Comment: So did any answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

1. it is .val()
2. you can push OR you can map
3. You can use a class so you do not need to list

NOTE: If there is no `value` attribute on the field, using `this.getAttribute("value")` on the `.get` examples will result in any field without value attribute to be omitted from the array instead of adding an empty value (Thanks @adz5A)

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jLsa80m9/7/

---

```js
var object1 = [];
$('#list1, #list2').each(function() {
  object1.push($(this).val())
})
console.log(object1);

// Smarter:
var object2 = $('#list1, #list2')
  .map(function(index,$list) {
    return $list.value; // or this.value or $(this).val();
  })
  .get();
console.log(object2);

// EVEN Smarter:
var object3 = $('.list')
  .map(function() {
    return this.value;
  })
  .get();
console.log(object3);

// The two following versions were posted by @rmn - I include them here for 
// completeness sake. Upvote his answer if you like them

// ES6 with jQuery
var object4 = $('#list1, #list2').get().map(el => el.value)
console.log(object4);

// ES6 without jQuery
var object5 = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list1, #list2')].map(el => el.value)
console.log(object5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="value1" id="list1" class="list" />
<input type="text" value="value2" id="list2" class="list" />
```

Comment: but what about the value of second element?

Comment: @bahazeityn you get all values using any of the above

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2). It returns as an array the set of matched DOM elements. You can easily combined this with `map` to retrieve the value of some attribute for instance

```
$("selector").map(function () { return this.getAttribute("value"); }).get();
```

Will get you the `value` attribute for the selection into an array. Note that you can use arrow function inside `map` as the second argument is the dom node itself, in my example the dom element is bounded to the lexical context `this`.

Comment: no it is not the same. A quick look at the docs on MDN shows that field access can return `undefined` whereas `getAttribute` returns null or empty string. I forgotten about that, thanks for reminding me. Moreover it is imo a really bad idea to **not** mix jQuery and the DOM, ie building jQuery objects all the time. Knowing one should not prevent you from knowing the other.

Comment: Hmm, I would not care about undefined here. In this case only your example creates a null entry. Which may of course be what you wanted, but in most cases I would prefer an empty string: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jLsa80m9/

Comment: Update. Your example actually does NOT add anything for the second field if it does not have an attribute when you use get() So your version is actually more correct

Comment: The issue is that it is **not** the same to use field access of attribute access. For instance if you are trying to access the `style` property or the style object. In the first case you may use `getAttribute` while in the other you will use field access to retrieve the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object.

Comment: I wonder what the actual difference is to have get().map() instead of .map().get() - the former is easier to read in my opinion now I have seen that version  for the first time

Comment: `map().get()` is using `$.fn.map` then `$.fn.get` on the collection while the other use `$.fn.get` then `Array.prototype.map`. The iteration method is not the same, especially for sparse collection.

Comment: Could you envision a situation where one would fail where the other would work?

Comment: Good question. The signatures of those two versions obviously differs... The context of this question is too simple for a good example (cannot find it right now :/). My main preoccupation would be composition. jQuery is **very** good at handling dom collection manipulation and composition. For instance exploring sub collections of each elements, filtering them and then merging back together: for side effect purposes (ie: removing, adding classes). However if you need data manipulation you probably should "escape" and use native collection methods. Not sure this is a good answer :/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery

```
$('#list1, #list2').get().map(el => el.value)
```

Without jQuery

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('#list1, #list2')].map(el => el.value)
```

Comment: ES6 but Very nice :)

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan .. means a lot coming from a javascript connoisseur.

Answer (score 0):

you can create array outside the loop and push it on each iteration

```
var object =[];
$('#list1, #list2').each(function(){ 
  object.push($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: you have `$list.val()` and i have `$(this).val()`, how come it is same ? BTW, basic will always be same which we need to follow as syntax :)

Comment: now you have changed it to `$(this).val()` .. so looks like your answer is same as mine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have id in your object, this is better:

```js
function getList(){
  var list = []
  $("#input1, #input2").each(function(){ 
    list.push({id: this.id, value: this.value });
  });
  
  
  console.log(list);
  
  /*
  OUTPUT:
  [
    {
      "id": "input1",
      "value": "v1"
    },
    {
      "id": "input2",
      "value": "v2"
    }
  ] */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="v1" />
<input id="input2" type="text" value="v2" />
<input type="button" onclick="getList()" value="get list" />
```